# Getting specific JSON data after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm building a React Native app that works with JSON data and shows the upcoming movies. It looks like this: https://image.ibb.co/kuOt9m/app.png . My problem is whenever I click the Summary button I get all the summaries, for all the movies. What i want is to get a specific summary for the movie I clicked. In the JSON there's a movie id that is totally unique and I guess I should set it on the Button or the CardSection itself. My code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import MovieSummary from './MovieSummary';

class SummaryList extends Component {

  state = { movies: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=22d8da68cffba151bfa886d5003aac02&language=en-US&page=1')
      .then(response => this.setState({ movies: response.data.results }));
  }

  renderSummary() {
    return this.state.movies.map(movie =>
      <MovieSummary key={movie.id} movie={movie} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {this.renderSummary()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default SummaryList;
```

then in another class i show the data like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const MovieSummary = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Text>
      {props.movie.overview}
    </Text>
  </View>
);

export default MovieSummary;
```

and then with a Router class (react-native-router-flux library) I use Router/Scene to connect the two screens. I'm gonna post the CardSection.js or Button.js code if it's gonna make it anymore clear and there's where I need to add an ID.

**edit: adding more information**

my CardSection.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CardSection = (props) => (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    *some view styles*
  }
};

export default CardSection;
```

my Button.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={onPress}
      style={styles.buttonStyle}
    >
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

const styles = {
  buttonStyle: {
    *button styles*
  },

  textStyle: {
    *text styles*
  }

};

export default Button;
```

Comment: can you please create a fiddle/plunker and post the link demonstrating the issue ?

Comment: Yes, please post the CardSection and Button code too. Are you using flux/redux for state management? You'll have the option of either setting the selected movie ID in your store state, or passing it through as a navigation prop.

Comment: @RobHogan I'm not using Redux for this. All I'm using is react, react-native, axios and react-native-router-flux. P.S. I updated the question with the code for CardSection and Button. I'm pretty new in React Native, is it necessary to use Redux for getting a specific data element?

Comment: Not necessary, I just guessed because you were using flux router that you might be using flux, but you don't have to. I'm struggling to reconcile the code above with the screenshot though. Where is your summary button? Where is `CardSection` used? Is `MovieSummary` the list item, or the single-movie summary screen?

Comment: @RobHogan I think the best I can do is showing you a github repo. I've uploaded all my .js files that actually matter, didn't upload all the others so it's not confusing. https://github.com/martinrangelov96/UpcomingMovies , hope you can somehow help me cause it's the last step for my app and it's a task that i have to do.. :( <3

Comment: @RobHogan By the way, i renamed MovieSummary.js to SummaryDetail.js, it's updated in the github repo, because it was kind of a bad name. I basically get the data and show it in MoviesList.js for Scene 1 and SummaryList.js for  Scene 2, and then I style it in MovieDetail.js and SummaryDetail.js (which I'm gonna style later, if I manage to fix my problem). I guess MovieView.js and SummaryView.js would be better names since I style them, now when I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, I think there's a bit of confusion about your second screen, you're calling it `SummaryList` and it's working on an array of movies - whereas if I understand correctly you want your second screen to just deal with one movie.

I'd rename a few things:

- `MoviesList` is fine
- `MovieDetail` -> `MoviesListItem` (these are rows in your `MovieList`, renaming to avoid confusion with your second screen)
- `SummaryDetail` is fine (this will be your single-movie scene. I'd probably actually call this `MovieDetail` but that would get confusing!)

Forget about `SummaryList` - we don't need it. You only have one list we're concerned about, that's `MoviesList`.

First, modify your `Router` so that you have a `MoviesList` and a `SummaryDetail` scene:

```
// Router.js
// ...
const RouterComponent = () => (
  <Router
    navigationBarStyle={styles.viewStyle}
    titleStyle={styles.textStyle}
    sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 53 }}
  >
    <Scene key="upcoming" component={MoviesList} title="Upcoming Movies" />
    <Scene
      key="summaryDetail"
      component={SummaryDetail}
      title="Summary Detail"
      leftButtonIconStyle={{ tintColor: '#a52a2a' }}
    />
  </Router>
);
// ...
```

So now your `MoviesListItem` is the component with a summary `Button` in it. This needs to lead to your `SummaryDetail` scene. You can navigate to your `SummaryDetail` scene by calling `Actions.summaryDetail()` from `react-native-router-flux`, but you actually want to tell this scene which movie it's dealing with. Pass the movie (which you already have as a prop of `MovieListItem`) as a param, via an argument to `Actions.summaryDetail(...)` like this:

```
// MovieListItem.js
// ...
    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
        Actions.summaryDetail({ movie: props.movie });  // <- Important bit!
      }}>
        Summary
      </Button>
    </View>
// ...
```

Now, you should have the movie available in your `SummaryDetail` screen as the `movie` prop.

```
// SummaryDetail.js
// ...
const SummaryDetail = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Text>
      {props.movie.overview}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
// ...
```

You might want to split off parts of `SummaryDetail` into separate presentational components later, and you might want to turn it into a class and use `componentDidMount` to fetch some extra movie detail you don't already have. But this should be enough to get you started with one movie on a second screen.